# Unity - Gameobject look at mouse

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've ran into a problem.

The basic setup I have right now, two objects: my camera, and my player object.

The player moves via Transform on WASD, and is supposed to rotate on mouse 
movement.

The camera is top down (At a slight "3ps" style angle, which keeps the player object centre to the camera's perspective, and rotates according to the players rotation.

This is the players movement script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public int playerSpeed = 8;  //players movement speed

    void Update () {
        if (Input.GetKey ("w")) 
        {
            transform.Translate (Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime * playerSpeed); //move forward
        }  
        if (Input.GetKey ("s")) 
        {
            transform.Translate (Vector3.back * Time.deltaTime * playerSpeed); //move backwards
        }  
        if (Input.GetKey ("a")) 
        {
            transform.Translate (Vector3.left * Time.deltaTime * playerSpeed); //move left
        }  
        if (Input.GetKey ("d")) 
        {
            transform.Translate (Vector3.right * Time.deltaTime * playerSpeed); //move right
        }
    }
}
```

This is the players rotation script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class mouseLook : MonoBehaviour {
    private Vector3 inputRotation;
    private Vector3 mousePlacement;
    private Vector3 screenCentre;

    void Update () {
        FindCrap();
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(inputRotation);
    }

    void FindCrap () {
        screenCentre = new Vector3(Screen.width * 0.5f,0,Screen.height * 0.5f);
        mousePlacement = Input.mousePosition;
        mousePlacement.z = mousePlacement.y;
        mousePlacement.y = 0;
        inputRotation = mousePlacement - screenCentre;
    } 
}
```

The result of everything I have shown is it rotates, but it doesn't rotate true to where the mouse physically is.

While I draw circles with the mouse, it will do full rotations, but not consistently point to where the mouse is. I'm not sure as to why.

The desired result is for the camera (child of player object) to follow the players movement and rotation, while the player moves with its movement script, and rotates to point true to where the mouse is.

Anyone got any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Edit: if it helps, the current rotation works like this.

drawing large circles with the mouse around the player gives a slower rotation, than extremely tight circles around the player.

Comment: i dont see any screen to world function, as far as i know you need to capture the mouse position and convert it to screen coords. so maybe it could be just that. hope this at least points you in the right direction. check out this doc http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure If I understand what you are trying to do. If you are trying to do something similar to the game "Dead Nation", then I would suggest something like this:

### MouseLook.cs

```
void Update()
{
    Vector3 mouse = Input.mousePosition;
    Vector3 mouseWorld = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(
                                                        mouse.x, 
                                                        mouse.y,
                                                        player.transform.position.y));
    Vector3 forward = mouseWorld - player.transform.position;
    player.transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(forward, Vector3.up);
}
```

If you want the camera to move and rotate along with the player then just make the camera a child of the player object.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. It seems like your code would be better suited for what I am after, but the code is throwing errors. I've defined the player argument, but the errors I receive are:

Type 'UnityEngine.Transform' dies not contain a definition for 'y' and no extension method 'y' (11,102) (CS1061)


No overload for method 'ScreenToWorldPoint' takes '3' arguments (11,50) (CS1501)

Comment: so to add to that, it takes fault with this line :   Vector3 mouseWorld = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mouse.x,mouse.y,player.transform.y);

Comment: Yes sorry I got a few error, this was my bad, let me edit.

Comment: If this works for you, please mark my answer as correct whenever you have the time. Thanks.

Comment: Your answer has patched my problem, certainly. But its lead to a screen flicker, and inverted mouse movement. Any idea on that one?

Comment: The inverted mouse movement (and I am assuming the problem only happens in the Y axis) should be solved by replacing the `mouse.y` with `Screen.height - mouse.y`. About the flickering, I am not sure, but do you have the camera as a child of the player?

Comment: Yes, the camera is a child of the player. I will test that new patch now

Comment: Then the screen flicker could be (not sure) because of the camera being child of the player.

Comment: Ok, so I applied the patch, and its still not working as hoped. I found that the flicker is due to rapidly quick rotation, so quick that you can't see it, much like heli rotors. Any ideas there?

Comment: If the patch did not work, then I will need you to give me a little bit of more detail on what exactly do you mean with "inverted mouse movement" and about the quick rotation, I would have to try it myself to see exactly what is happening.

Comment: You know what, I fixed it. I made an empty game object, hid it in the player, childed that to the player, then childed the camera to that. Thank you very much man.

Comment: What do you mean by **hid it in the player, childed that to the player**?

Comment: Anyway thank you for marking the answer, although technically it didn't help achieve perfectly what you needed.

Comment: Well you certainly got it 80% of the way there. One thing I dont understand about unity and C#, is why can't I define movement and rotation by coords? like" if (input) {transform.translate(x,y+10,z)}
This would make my life so much easier.

Comment: Well I'm not sure what you mean by "coordinates". `transform.translate(x, y + 10, z)` is not coordinates?

Comment: Sorry, coords is not the right word. I would rather be able to write each individual axis rather than transform.translate.up

Comment: Ah now I understand. Well I guess that they tried to make it more oriented to OOP rether than friendly oriented.

Answer (score 0):

a sollution that worked for me but its in 2D

also dont make the camera a child of the player but use a slurping script as shown in this video.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MFQhpwc6cKE&t=3s&ab_channel=Brackeys

```
public Camera cam;
Transform my;


void Awake()
{
    cam = Camera.main;
    my = GetComponent<Transform>();
}


void Update()
{
    // Distance from camera to object.  We need this to get the proper calculation.
    float camDis = cam.transform.position.y - my.position.y;

    // Get the mouse position in world space. Using camDis for the Z axis.
    Vector3 mouse = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, camDis));

    float AngleRad = Mathf.Atan2(mouse.y - my.position.y, mouse.x - my.position.x);
    float angle = (180 / Mathf.PI) * AngleRad;

    my.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, angle);
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).